# Why is sys.path showing non-existent items (which cause import problems)?

Tags: python, egg

I'm seeing some additional items in `sys.path` which 1) don't exist and 2) cause problems with imports (specifically with `Nose`).

Basically, I've created a package (lets call it `foo`) which I use in multiple projects. The project I'm working on at the moment can import everything from `foo` without issue, but when I run `Nose` I get import errors:

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (No module named foo)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "/path/to/my-project/file.py", line 6, in <module>
    from foo import *
ImportError: No module named foo

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.004s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

When I spit out the path I get:

```
["/path/to/my-project/foo", 
 "/path/to/my-project/foo", 
 ..., 
 "/usr/virtualenvs/my-project/lib/python2.6/site-packages/foo-py2.6.egg", 
 ...]
```

`/path/to/my-project/foo` doesn't exist. If I pop the first 2 entries off `sys.path` everything works fine.

Can someone explain to me why those items are showing up when, really, the only one that should be in the list is the one installed into the virtualenv?

And how do I stop this from happening in the future? Is it something to do with the `setup.py` in `foo`?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have anything in `$PYTHONPATH`? This will put entries in sys.path even within a virtualenv enviroment.

Try `unset PYTHONPATH` in bash (if you use bash) and then see what your `sys.path` contains.

Answer (score 0):

Look for `.pth` files anywhere on the path.  These files (e.g., `easy-install.pth`) can contain additional sys.path entries (one per line).